# A policy evaluation with a dependent variable which is continuous and in (0,1) interval

Tags: logistic, categorical-data, matching, probit, social-science

I am conducting research in which I want to investigate the effect of tax incentives on research and development intensity in a group of firms. I have access to the data of a survey that:

- It's only for one year. (It has a cross-sectional nature).
- The companies were not chosen randomly, but those companies that
  conduct research and development.
- It includes nearly 3000 companies, about 20-30% of which have been
  exposed to tax incentives.(As I know, there are about 1,500 companies
  that have done research and development but not cooperated with the
  questioners)
- My dependent variable, which is the share of research and development
  expenses to the total expenses of the company, has a number between 0
  and 1.

I'm having a little trouble choosing the right econometric method for this research.